# Stop a sheduleAtFixedRate task in the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor Java

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

Say I have this bloated example. 
What I would expect to happen is to get a couple of numbers in the console around three times, then I'd expect the "The task is stopped" line to be printed, and then I'd get no more numbers.

So I'd like to stop a task from being executed. So far I've tried to `cancel(true)` the future, `executor.shutdownNow)(` and `executor.shutdown()` the executor, but none of those lead to a behavior that I've described above. Am I missing something? Is there a way to cancel this task?

```java
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        executor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
        final int rareNumber = 302330233;
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            int x = 0;
            while (true) {
                x++;
                if(x % rareNumber == 0) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
            }
        }, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(3_000);
        // I'd like to stop a task here.
        System.out.println("The task is stopped");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is `executor.shutdownNow()`. This causes the thread to be interrupted.

However your thread is not be waiting / sleeping at that time, so you don't get `IterruptedException` so you need to check `Thread.intrrupted()` flag:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    final int rareNumber = 302330233;
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        int x = 0;
        while (true) {
            x++;
            if(x % rareNumber == 0) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }

            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3_000);

    executor.shutdownNow();
    // I'd like to stop a task here.
    System.out.println("The task is stopped");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But why does the executor not stop the task if it sees that the thread has been interrupted. I've tried reading the Javadocs for the involved classes, but I can't seem to understand.

Plus, isn't it too harsh to `shutdownNow` the executor? What if I wanted to reuse later? I could, of course, just reassign the `executor` to a `new` executor, but it seems like there could be a better solution.

Comment: Regarding the interrupt/stop thread - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html. If you want to stop single task you can call future.cancel(true) with the task modification as above..

Answer (score 1):

First, when you find a correct number at one execution, you should break that `while` loop to finish that execution cycle.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    int x = 0;
    while (true) {
        x++;
        if(x % rareNumber == 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
            break;
        }
    }
}, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then you can cancel the future as follows to stop the fixed-rate scheduler.

```
    Thread.sleep(3_000);
    // I'd like to stop a task here.
    future.cancel(true);
    System.out.println("The task is stopped");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should consider in your code :

- You never shutDown your pool and threads in this pool are not Daemon Threads so if you create your Pool , the main JVM process will be prevented from shutting down - so you should close your pool. Shutting down the pool will interrupt the threads that are processing tasks. How to do it is described in [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) docs :

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

- If you want to make your task cancellable there are 2 common ways to do it :

  1. Check the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` status in a loop
  2. If you call some method that are blocking and can throw `InterruptedException` you can handle this exception. It will be thrown when the Thread is interrupted.
- as you have set `executor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);` the Threads will not be be recreated if they are Interrupted. If you did not set this flag - it is a good idea to preserve the interruption status, as you are not the owner of those threads and you do not know what interruption means to them. But you are not using any methods that can throw `InterruptedException` so it is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

What if the `Runnable` passed to a service is not this loop, but some other, potentially blocking, computation?


Say I need to tweet something in my `Runnable`. I presume I'd send an HTTP request, or access some kind of Java Twitter API, which is potentially time consuming.

What if such `Runnable` is canceled with `future.cancel()` in the middle of some computation? Does it mean that I have to check `Thread.interrupted()` before I do the computation?

Comment: `Future.cancel` will set the interruption flag for the thread that the task is being processed with. Your task should be responsive to cancellation in one of two ways that I described in my answer if you want it to be cancellable.